# Swagger adding description to enums

Tags: java, swagger-2.0

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Rule {

    private RuleType type; //enum
    private String value;
}
```

The enum is:

```
public enum RuleType {
    TYPE_A, TYPE_B, TYPE_C;
}
```

Now each rule type the values are different. TYPE_A requires a number 1 through 10, TYPE_B is true or false, and TYPE_C is a string. I am trying to add swagger annotations to the enum so that the documentation can show this, something like this:

```
public enum RuleType {
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "1 - 10")
    TYPE_A, 
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "True or False")
    TYPE_B, 
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "String")
    TYPE_C;
}
```

But this doesn't work. The swagger produced just ignores the properties on the enums. Is there a way to create documentation like this?

Comment: How can an enum value itself have multiple values? If the enum is `TYPE_A`, it would always be `TYPE_A` itself right? If it can have multiple values, it should be of a different data type and not an enum. For eg, if `TYPE_B` can be true or false, you should be using a boolean instead right? I believe you need to change your class design.

Comment: OpenAPI Specification (and, by extension, Swagger tools) does not support descriptions for individual enum values (here's a related [feature request](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/348)). You'll probably need to specify these descriptions in the annotations for `RuleType`.

Comment: Any update on this? I use SpringDoc 1.4.3 and am facing the same issue.

Comment: There is a github project that apparently solves this: https://github.com/hoereth/springfox-enum-plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this as you like. But there is another simple solution which you want.

```
public class Rule {

    @ApiModelProperty(value = 
            "TYPE_A must be 1 - 10\n" +
            "TYPE_B must be True or False\n" +
            "TYPE_C must be String")
    private RuleType type; //enum
    private String value;
}
```

You can see final result of this code with this link:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMA6N.png

Answer (score 0):

As @Helen mentioned, it's currently not possible to set a description for enums. However, you can assign a description to the property, as @Azamat suggested. Here's a similar approach using Microprofile OpenAPI annotations.

```
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.Schema;

public class Foobar {
  private String value;

  @Schema(
      name = "type",
      description = "TYPE_A - [1 - 10], TYPE_B - [True or False], TYPE_C - [String]")
  private RuleType type;
}
```

Swagger UI

```
Foobar{
value   string
type    string
TYPE_A - [1 - 10], TYPE_B - [True or False], TYPE_C - [String]

Enum:
[ TYPE_A, TYPE_B, TYPE_C ]
}
```

[image]